# Ubuntu 21.04 boot hangs at logo

Tags: boot, networking, command-line

I tried to install playonlinux on Ubuntu 21.04.  When the installation was finished, I had lost my wifi connection.  So, I tried to re-boot, however boot-up stalls at the ubuntu logo.

Hitting escape at that point I get a screen with "Dependency failed for SSSD" services.  The services listed are NSS, toFS, PAC, vice, PAM, SSH, Sudo.

At the first stage of booting I can escape to the Grub menu.  From there, choosing advanced options, I get a list of three kernels:  vmlinuz-5.11.0-18-generic, 5.8.0-55-generic, and 4.15.0-1008-oem.  Trying to boot the first two gets me as far as the ubuntu logo, the third hangs on a dark screen (with one line of text at the top).

At the advanced menu, of course, I can also select recovery mode for each of these kernels.  Recovery mode brings me to a command line where I can log in at root.  That is where I am now.  I am looking for references on how to proceed, but so far haven't found a solution.

I still can't access the internet: network-manager is not found.  The machine is Dell XPS13, factory-installed Ubuntu.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can get to the Grub menu the problem is NOT Grub and Boot Repair is useless. Installing PoL couldn't result in the graphical environment not loading, there must have been something else you did. Please try to remember and then edit the question accordingly. Meanwhile you may try, from the Grub menu, to boot an older kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.